# Significance of 'Model' in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am NEW in MVC3 so bear with me. I created default ASP.NET MVC3 application. There is a simple registration page in there.

So that calling procedure goes like this:

1. View (Register.cshtml) calls Controller (AccountController.cs)
2. Controller calls Model (AccountModels.cs)

I want to know, why there is a need of Model? I mean, what MODEL should supposed to do? Any answers will be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model should represent your business domain, and it should reflect your application's purpose. View is the UI to expose your business domain, and controller is the bridge between your domain and UI.

Answer (score 6):

Models represent data. If your view has no data to load, you don't need a model!

Watch this video- it should explain better than I can in a short comment: [Understanding Models, Views, and Controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/understanding-models-views-and-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Model is everything that the other two aren't.   View is pure presentation, Controller is the logic of the view, and model is the stuff you're actually viewing.

Answer (score 0):

The model holds that non static data that will be displayed on the page - the View has access to the model and it's properties in order to render them.